# How to disable asset loading with selenium?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara, phantomjs, poltergeist

I am using Selenium web driver with capybara and headless browsers poltergeist. When doing test, I want to disable some css and js such as google analytics.

I have made tons of search, and also I have read all of documentations. But I did not find any solution.

What is the proper way of disabling assets with selenium web driver?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that disabling (for example) google analytics is something you would want to do for the whole test and development environments. I would do this within the view that renders that javascript. Something like

```
<% if Rails.env == "production" %>
  my google analytics js
<% end %>
```